# Finding tangents to a cycloid

Tags: calculus, parametric

here's the question I don't really get the second part of the question.. it uses parametric curve equation to solve.

> A curve $\mathcal C$, a cycloid, is defined by $x=r(\theta-\sin\theta), y=r(1-\cos\theta)$, where $r$ is the radius of the corresponding circle.
>   1. Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point where $\theta=\frac\pi3$.
>   2. At what points is the tangent horizontal?  Where is it vertical?

[(original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ6dg.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please see here for a tutorial on how to type mathematics formulas: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: This is actually not a completely trivial problem, because the cycloid has cusps where both $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are zero, and a more careful analysis is needed to determine the slope of the tangent line at these points.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$

Comment: In this case you mean $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$.

Comment: @MJD, the problem initially had a different screenshot -- http://prntscr.com/6gb75j (if it's still up).

Comment: Holy cow, that is a completely different question.

Comment: i got $\displaystyle\frac{(\sin\theta)}{(1-cos\theta)}$ then i plug in $\displaystyle\theta=\frac\pi3$ into the question and i got $\sqrt{3}$ as my slope.